# login failed for user 'sa' in sql server ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

Working on the deployed SSIS Package .. Unfortunately SSIS job is failing while running that package .. I am getting Following Error;

> NIGHTLYUPDATE_v3:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login failed for user 'sa'.". An
>   OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot open database
>   "DB_DATA" requested by the login. The login failed.".

I have researched on it but most of the solutions are to change the protection Level but is there any other way to resolve this issue ..

Comment: 1. Are you able to login to the SQL instance via SSMS directly using sa?
2. What's the default database assigned for sa account?
3. Which versions of SQL database and SSIS are you using?
4. How are you deploying the SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to fix it is to correct the connection string so that it uses a valid SQL UserName and Password.   Sounds like you currently have an incorrect password in the connection string.

The best way to fix it is to use windows authentication and have the job run by a domain account that has all the necessary permissions to your database "DB_DATA".

Comment: User is valid cause i can login with that user in SSMS with those credentials and can access to DB_DATA

Comment: And Package is aready deployed how can i change the authentication via Windows in SSMS

Comment: i Also try to change the credentials from deloyed package configuration but it is still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying the failure occuring at the SQL Server Job, it is best to look into assigning credentials followed by a proxy. Use that proxy within the job definition while executing the package. Additionally as best practise it is best to not use 'sa' account and create a domain account or SQL Server account.

Here is the link - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was db is restricted to Single_user i changed it to Multi_user it is working now